# How to dynamically add scripts to new webpages in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm currently learning javascript without any frameworks. How do you guys redirect to another html file, then assign a script to it dynamically?

So far, what I have done is:

```
onClick()
{
    window.location = newpage.html;
    var script = createElement('script');
     script.src = dynamic + 'script.js';
    var body = document.findbyID('body');
     body.appendChild(src);
}
```

One of the examples of the dynamic script goes like this:

```
function addText()
{
    var text = createElement('p');
    text.innerhtml = sometext;
    var textHolder = findbyid('div_somewhere_in_html');
    body.appendChild(text);
}
```

The above code doesn't show the text inside the new webpage. The window.location command works. But after dynamically adding a text, it will not show up inside the new webpage. If I would console.log(window.location), it would only show my localhost:3000.

EDIT:
All files are hosted locally.

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Is the redirected page yours? If so, you can pass a query string param with the script address, and then onload (of the other page) use a script to load the dynamic script based on the param.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira doing this for embedded stuff

Comment: @EricFortis yes, this all files are local. On what object will I call the onload on? would it be window.onload?

Comment: While it is possible to have the client side web browser load JavaScript, beyond your page script, from a remote server, it is not typically done except when injecting 3rd party stuff such as embedded maps, tweets, stuff like that. If you own both pages/URLs it's best to pack all your scripts into a single file so your page(s) load fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you own the target page, you can load (instead of pushing) a script based on a query string parameter. For example:

**newpage.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
  const dynamic = new URL(location).searchParams.get('script-prefix');
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = dynamic + 'script.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**anotherpage.html**

When clicking the following link, `newpage.html` will load and execute a script called `MyPrefixscript.js`.

```
<html>
<body>
   <a href="/newpage.html?script-prefix=MyPrefix">My Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, I used an anchor, but `window.location = '/newpage.html?script-prefix=MyPrefix'` would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for this Eric, but the  '/newpage.html/?script-prefix=MyPrefix' will throw a 404 Error in the console
EDIT:
does it have to be 'script-prefix'? I'm assuming it can be any variable name

Comment: Oh I figured it out! Thank you Eric!

Comment: It should just be window.location = '/newpage.html?script-prefix=MyPrefix'
Remove the slash '/' before the '?'