# getting data from function for another webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I have a function. Using that I can select some boxes in my page(step3.html). Also using that function I can identify which box I choose. Now I want to get out that peace of data(which box I choose) from that function and use it for change something in my other web page(step4.html)

I cant use the data inside the function, because they are separate pages (I think). Also I use return method and it didn't work. because every time before select a box, return method run.

is there's a way, inside the function use that data(which box I choose) for my other page(step.html) ?

```
$("..").click(function{

  ddj(this);

})

function ddj(xx){

   var whatBoxClicked = .... ;
   return whatBoxClicked ;
}

var peaceOfData = ddj();
```

Comment: Here's a similar answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324644/529725

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your code is OK so far.You will receive the data from the function and it will be stored in the variable `pieceOfData`. However, if you want to *use* that data you will have to *send* it o the second page in some way. One way of doing it would be to append it as an argument. You could, for example, add the argument to the `href` attribute of the link leading to the next page:

```js
const [choose,choice,go]=".choose,.choice,.go".split(",").map(sel=>document.querySelector(sel)),href=go.getAttribute("href")+"?choice=";
choose.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  let whatBoxClicked=ddj(ev);
  choice.textContent=whatBoxClicked;
  go.setAttribute("href",href+whatBoxClicked)
})

// the following function can theoretically be defined in a separate file ("script.js") 
// and can be used from more than one page
function ddj(ev){
 return ev.target.textContent;
}
```

```html
<div class="choose">
  <div>box1</div>
  <div>box2</div>
  <div>box3</div>
  <div>box4</div>
</div>
<span class="choice">no box</span> chosen.
<a class="go" href="step4.html">go to next step</a>
```

On the next page you will have to "pick up" the data by using something like

```
let choice=new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('choice');
```